# Why is it not showing?

Tags: transactions

Someone from blockchain wallet send me some Bitcoin to my jubiter wallet #1BtQi9JmvTvyEBmbGvMQLUCEdUXQyZF21Y and it been two days still havnet receive nothing but it said it's confirmed what going on? Help please thank you

Answer (score 0):

According to [Blockstream block explorer](https://blockstream.info/address/1BtQi9JmvTvyEBmbGvMQLUCEdUXQyZF21Y), it looks like you have 1 confirmed output. So most likely it's an issue relating to the wallet you're using.

Unfamiliar with the Jubiter wallet but do you know whether it connect to Jubiter's nodes through a web/app, or do you have to connect it to a full node running on your machine? My guess is the former. I'd double check that the address above is the correct as well.

Maybe someone else knows Jubiter better.

Comment: How can the person. That sent me the Bitcoin get the Bitcoin back ... And I'm just using the website no app I'm new to this so help please

Comment: And do I got go wait on a business day for the transaction to go thru I did it on Friday night...

Comment: @Trub there is no concept of 'business day' for Bitcoin. The network runs 24/7 without interruption. If Jubiter wallet lets you hold your own private keys (ie, you have a seed phrase backup, in most cases), then there is likely just an issue with your wallet syncing to the network. If Jubiter is a custodial service (they hold the private keys), then you'll need to contact their customers service to have things set straight.

Comment: @chytrik so what should I do call them and what a private key